# Good pattern for a loader in Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, preloader

I'm working on an AngularJS-based business app. In most common scenario before I show the view I'm loading some data by making a few $http POST calls. I want to show a loader in the meantime. So far I've done it by $broadcasting an event and catching it elsewhere with dedicated controller. This allows me to have a single loader per web page, which is fine. At least for now.
But maybe are there any better approaches?

Comment: The best place is to use HTTP Interceptor in Angular JS. Try the below link:

https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

 Please find my answer and approach below

Answer (score 0):

Instead of broadcasting the events yourself you can take advantage of the start and finish events that the route provider are throwing apon view-change.

Angular router ($route)

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e) {
    openLoader();
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e) {
    closeLoader();
});
```

ui-router ($state)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    openLoader();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    closeLoader();
});
```

And  you might want to add a filter here if you have states/routes where the loader should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The approach:
You can have a block level element in your main page containing gif loader or "Loading..." text. The visibility of this element should be hidden by default.

Inside Request Interceptor you can make the block level element visible and inside Response interceptor if all the request are completed and there are no pending requests you can hide this block level element.

You can achieve this functionality in a common place and so far have found this as a best approach